# how to show an image at the top of a views page

Tags: views

I want to show an image at the top of each page. The pages are created by views. The images not slide show. it is like a banner which always displaying in the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are more ways to achieve this:

- Block - you create simple block with img html in it and add it to the desired pages using block configuration.
- Views header - in view settings, add header with custom text and add the img html in it.
- Views attachment - if the images should be dynamic (e.g. some nodes with image field), you can create another view of attachment type which displays these images and attach it before your page view.

and some more...

Comment: thank you m1n0 i tried the custom text but there is no option for adding image

Comment: Theres no option for image, I know, but you just write simple html <img> tag (http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_img.asp). Please accept my answer if it was helpful.

Comment: If you install the ckeditor module, you can probably drag the image from the filesystem into CKEditor if HTML is too difficult.